# Getting error "Input string is too long for MQI field" while connecting to IBMMQ

Tags: node.js, ibm-mq

I am connecting to IBMMQ which has ssl. I am able to connect to this  IBM MQ using Java code and using MQ explorer. Now trying to connect using Node . I followed code given [here](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-mqi-nodejs/blob/master/samples/amqsconntls.js)  by replacing all required values with the one which I got and then when i execute I get error

```
D:\IBMMQ\node_modules\ibmmq\lib\mqiutils.js:46
      throw new RangeError(errstring);
      ^

RangeError: Input string is too long for MQI field
    at Object.exports.setMQIString (D:\\IBMMQ\node_modules\ibmmq\lib\mqiutils.js:46:13)
    at Object.exports._copyCDtoC (D:\\IBMMQ\node_modules\ibmmq\lib\mqcd.js:329:5)
    at Object.exports._copyCNOtoC (D:\\IBMMQ\node_modules\ibmmq\lib\mqcno.js:131:21)
    at connx (D:\\IBMMQ\node_modules\ibmmq\lib\mqi.js:754:21)
    at Object.exports.Connx (D:\\IBMMQ\node_modules\ibmmq\lib\mqi.js:727:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\IBMMQ\TestMQOMS.js:45:4)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
```

Since it might be string length issue I tried  updating my cipher value to  just "xyz" but then i see error

```
MQ call failed in CONNX: MQCC = MQCC_FAILED [2] MQRC = MQRC_KEY_REPOSITORY_ERROR [2381]
```

Any idea how i can fix 'RangeError:' .

Comment: You haven't actually bothered to say WHICH cipherspec you have tried to set. My guess is that you are attempting to use the same name as you have used in a Java program. But the nodejs support is based on the C client which will often have different names, and must fit in 32 chars/

Comment: Usually when asking a question about code on StackOverflow, it is normal to show your code, at least a small snippet of the code that you think might be problematic.

Comment: ya, i used same code  as mentioned here https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-mqi-nodejs/blob/master/samples/amqsconntls.js. Only values changed.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by  Mark Taylor , i used  less size cipher in matching cipher list. Code worked.